# Which statistical tests should I use for this data?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, dataset, histogram

I have been given data from Kickstarter ( Kickstarter is a crowd funding platform that helps people garner funds for their business ideas).  The data has about 15,000 rows and about 10 - 15 columns. The task is to analyze the data and do a writeup about how we would consult new kickstarter business campaigns. Vaguely speaking the way kickstarter works is that  you establish a monetary goal and a date when your campaign is over.  Donators can pledge any amount of money they want. If you don't meet your goal by the due date then the donators get all their money and you failed, but if you have met or exceeded your goal then you have succeeded and get to have the money that was pledged by each donator.

For each of the 15,000 kickstarter business ideas, in the data, it shows whether it failed or succeeded. It shows what the goal was, how much was funded, how many donators there were, how many updates were made during the campaign, what type of business, where the business will be located, the time of year of the proposal, and how many rewards the campaign offered( kickstarter lets you send rewards to the donators depending on how much they pledged).  Which statistical tests should I use in regards to showing which variables were the most significant, which graphs/plots should I use? Any sort of recommendation would be helpful. I am a beginner in stats. Thank you!

Comment: Try looking at logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of using Logistic regression. How much of an issue is it if there is collinearity? Would it negatively impact Logistic regression?